# using BufReader reading files line by line, stored into an array

Tags: file, rust

in the code below the creation of the string buffer 
is a quickest way i have found as there's no allocation deallocation done 
if i understand correctly

```rust
pub extern fn rust_print_file() -> *mut PackChar {

    //set min size to 50 - avoid expanding when line count is 50 or less
    let mut out_vec = Vec::with_capacity(50);
    let mut curdr = env::current_dir().unwrap();//get path to file dir
    let fl_str = "file_test.txt";
    curdr.push(fl_str);//created full path to be used

    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(curdr).unwrap());

    //here i try to accommodate each line in a struct

    let mut line_index = 0;
    for line in file.lines() {

        let cur_line = line.unwrap();

        let loclbuf_size = cur_line.len();
        let mut loclbuf = String::with_capacity(buffer_size);
        //i tried two ways
        loclbuf.push_str(cur_line.unwrap()); // can't be done
        loclbuf.push_str(line.unwrap()); // can't be done too

        let pack_char = PackChar {
            int_val: line_index,
            buffer_size: loclbuf_size as i32,
            buffer: loclbuf.as_ptr() as *mut _,
        };
        line_index+=1;
        mem::forget(buffer);
        out_vec.push(pack_char);
    }
    Box::into_raw(out_vec.into_boxed_slice()) as *mut _ 
}
```

this is the struct i am using to pass to C#

```rust
#[repr(C)]
pub struct PackChar {
    pub int_val: c_int,
    pub buffer: *mut c_char,
    pub buffer_size: c_int,
}
```

when generating some dummy text 
i have checked, and it passes data correctly to "the other side" to use it.
but not with the read line task, produced text as coded above.

and this is another way i have tried, although i prefer the above code but this one  throws a compile error.

error: use of moved value: `buffer` [E0382] on `forget(buffer)`

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_return_file_read_lines() -> *mut PackChar {
    let mut out_vec = Vec::with_capacity(50);

    let mut curdr = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let fl_str = "file_test.txt";
    curdr.push(fl_str);


    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(curdr).unwrap());

    let mut lindex = 0;
    for line in file.lines() {

       let tmpbuffer = line.unwrap().into_bytes();
       let tmpbuffer_size = buffer.len();

       let pack_char = PackChar {
           int_val: lindex,
           buffer_size: tmpbuffer_size as i32,
           buffer: Box::into_raw(tmpbuffer.into_boxed_slice()) as *mut _
       };
       lindex+=1;
       mem::forget(buffer);
       out_vec.push(pack_char);

    }
    Box::into_raw(out_vec.into_boxed_slice()) as *mut _
}
```

**Edit**
as long as the type of buffer :

`buffer: loclbuf.as_ptr() as *mut _,`

i could pass the the data correctly to c#. 
so **how could i read lines that way so each will be stored into buffer as described ?**

Comment: There's no *question* here that I can see. You've simply pasted some examples of code and state that it doesn't work. Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) that exemplifies your problem and ask a direct, specific question.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for trying to help, i tried to read a file line by line. then store each line into a struct. the problem is i could not find a way to correctly assign the line to the buffer, the question is what is the correct way . thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as it appear now it seem that there was a bug in my visual studio, it's not the first time it ever happen but as i am new to rust i was sure that the code is wrong .

this is what is working for me, i will be happy to have comments and suggestions

```
extern crate libc;
use std::env;
use libc::c_char;
use libc::c_int;
use std::mem;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufRead};
use std::fs::File;

#[repr(C)]
pub struct PackChar {
    pub int_val: c_int,
    pub buffer: *mut c_char, // changed
    pub dbuffer_size: c_int, // added
}


#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rust_print_file() -> *mut PackChar {
    let mut out_vec = Vec::with_capacity(50 as usize);

    let mut cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap();
    let fl_str = "file_test.txt";
    cwd.push(fl_str);
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(cwd).unwrap());

    for (index, line) in file.lines().enumerate() {

        let buffer = line.unwrap();
        let buffer_size = buffer.len();

        let pack_char = PackChar {
            int_val: index as i32,
            dbuffer_size: buffer_size as i32,
            buffer: buffer.as_ptr() as *mut _,
        };
        mem::forget(buffer); // don't deallocate memory
        out_vec.push(pack_char);
    }

    Box::into_raw(out_vec.into_boxed_slice()) as *mut _ // changed
}
```

Comment: You use panic for error handling, but to panic in rust in a function called from C or other language, will unwind across the boundary and this is UB. You should use catch_panic to avoid panicking across the boundary. And better, where possible, use non-panicking way of handling errors -- see `try!` in the [error handling guide.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/book/error-handling.html)

Comment: To properly reconstitute a string [you **need** all three of pointer, length, capacity.](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_raw_parts). So you need to keep the capacity around if you plan to allow freeing your datastructure by calling back into rust.

Comment: "*i was sure that the code is wrong*" - So there wasn no problem? Then the question should be closed. It isn't a very useful question anyway.